# for loop function called twice, for loop only occurs in second call

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have the following helper function I created, which is to serve to create an array of a date range. Assume that the `holidays` variable is an array of ISO date strings and is already populated elsewhere in my vue app.

```js
export const parseAvailableDates = (
    startDate,
    endDate,
    holidays
) => {
    console.log({ startDate, endDate, holidays });
    let dates = [];
    for (
        let i = new Date(startDate);
        i <= new Date(endDate);
        i.setDate(i.getDate() + 1)
    ) {
        console.log("running");
        const thisDate = i.toLocaleString("en-US", localeString);
        if (!thisDate.includes("Sunday") && !thisDate.includes("Saturday")) {
            const formattedDate = changeLocaleDateToISOString(thisDate);
            if (!holidays.includes(formattedDate)) {
                dates.push(formattedDate);
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(dates);
    return dates;
};
```

Now, I need to call this function twice in my Vue app in the same function, once to initially populate the dates based on the range between `startAssignments` and `lastDateToSubmitWork`, and again to reset the `availableDates` array to the range between `startAssignments` and `endDate`.

```js
// called here

    const startAssignments = `2022-02-09T00:00:00.000+04:00`
    const lastDateToSubmitWork = `2022-08-19T00:00:00.000+04:00`
    const endDate = `2022-08-31T00:00:00.000+04:00`

      let availableDates = [];
      availableDates = parseAvailableDates(
        startAssignments,
        lastDateToSubmitWork,
        holidays
      );
      console.log(availableDates);

// also called here

          availableDates = parseAvailableDates(
            startAssignments,
            endDate,
            holidays
          );
```

When these two calls happens, the initial `console.log()` in `parseAvailableDates()` shows the startDate, endDate, and holidays properly defined on both calls. However, on the first call, the `for` loop never runs, and the function returns `[]`, and on the second call, the `for` loop does run, and the function returns a properly populated array of ISO date strings.

I don't understand why the first loop doesn't run properly, but the second does.

Comment: What is `localeString`?

Comment: The script crashes on the first call because of that undefined variable.

Comment: @Barmar just put an empty array in its stead

Comment: Now I get an error trying to call `changeLocaleDateToISOString()`. Can you please post a [mre] so I don't have to fix all these things myself?

Comment: You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.